# How to check for the existence of a get parameter in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to python and flask.

I know that I can fetch a GET parameter with request.args.get(varname);. I wanted to check whether a GET request to my server is specifying and optional parameter or not.

Flask documentation didn't helped much.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can actually use the default value,

```
opt_param = request.args.get("something")
if opt_param is None:
    print "Argument not provided"
```

Comment: @JakobBowyer This is not a claim, and I upvote you answer, but I think for novice in python more immediately useful to show pythonic way ;)

Comment: What happens if the query parameter has no value? It's a valid query string, and it represents a "flag", not an option.

Answer (score 25):

A more Pythonic way to do the same would be using the `in` operator:

```
if 'varname' in request.args:
    # parameter 'varname' is specified
    varname = request.args.get('varname')
else:
    # parameter 'varname' is NOT specified
```

Answer (score 9):

```
page = request.args.get("page", 0, type=int)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check it with this code:

```py
name = request.args.get("name", default=None, type=str)
```

Comment: please add some context about your answer.